# Realloc makes my program crash

Tags: c, realloc

I need to reallocate a matrix of char but it doesn't work.

I tried many solution bu no one works.

The program compiles but after runnig it crashs on the realloc().

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Xy {
  int x;
  int y;
}Xy;

typedef struct Nodo{
  Xy destination;
  struct Nodo *next;
}Nodo;

char **matrD;
char **matrU;
char **matr;

int i,j;

Nodo *header;

Xy pos;
Xy dimD;
Xy dimU;
Xy startD;
Xy startU;
Xy *dim;
Xy *start;
char flor='d';

int *dimen;
int dimenD[]={10,6};
int dimenU[]={10,6};
int gradi=0;
char sens[4];

void addCol(){
    int newsize=dim->x+2;
  for(i=0;i<dim->y;i++){
    printf("ciao\n");
    printf("%d",newsize);
    printf("%c\n",matr[i]);
    matr[i]=realloc(matr[i],sizeof(char)*newsize); <-----it crash here
    printf("ciao\n");
  }
  dim->x=dim->x+2;
}



void addRow(){
  dim->y=dim->y+2;
 // matr= (char*)realloc(matr,dim->y);
}

void loop() {

  addCol();
 // stampamatrix();
}

void main() {

  sens[0]='t';

  startD.x=0;
  startD.y=0;
  startU.x=0;
  startU.y=0;
  pos.x=0;
  pos.y=0;
  dimD.x=1;
  dimD.y=1;
  dimU.x=0;
  dimU.y=1;
  dim=&dimD;
  dimen=dimenD;
  start=&startD;
  matrD =malloc(sizeof(char*)*dimD.x);
  matrD[0] =malloc(sizeof(char)*dimD.x);
  matrU =malloc(sizeof(char*)*dimU.y);
  matrU[0] =malloc(sizeof(char)*dimU.x);


  loop();

}
```

Comment: "If nothing helps, read the manual." I suggest to read the description of `realloc`.

Comment: First of all, don't reassign to the same pointer you use when calling `realloc`. If `realloc` fails it will return `NULL` and you will loose the original p ointer (which otherwise would still point to valid allocated memory). Second of all, what's with all the global variables? Do they all really need to be global? You know you can pass arguments to your own functions?

Comment: There are also other more or less severe problems in your code, the first that caught my eye was this call `printf("%c\n",matr[i])`. Here `matr[i]` is a *pointer* and not a character. Use `"%p"` to print a pointer.

Comment: In addition to Joachim Pileborg's comment: in `printf("%c\n",matr[i]);` you use `matr[i]` before it has been initialized. In other words, upon the first call of `addCol`, `matr` is NULL.

Comment: And why all those pointers? What is the use of e.g. `dim` or `start`? Why not access `dimD` or `startD` directly?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't initialize `matr` anywhere, which means it's a null pointer (since it's a global variable it's "zero-initialized" which means `NULL` for pointers).

So when you try to dereference `matr` using e.g. `matr[i]` then you will have *undefined behavior* and most likely a crash.

You should learn how to use a debugger, because then this problem would have been very obvious. Running in a debugger would have the debugger stop when the crash happens, at the location of the crash. It would then allow you to walk up the function call stack so you could reach your code (if the debugger haven't already stopped at your code), and then you could check the values of involved arguments. Checking `matr[i]` in the debugger would have cause the debugger to tell you it's not a valid pointer and you would have seen this problem very quickly without any help.

Comment: Not sure that this is the only problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't allocate memory for `matr`, and so you cause undefined behaviour by trying to access `matr[i]`.